# Multiple ajax requests, only one inserting into the DB?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have user based created rows. When you click "add new row" some content is cloned and appended.

Each cloned content has its own textarea and each row gets a row key.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rowkey" value="0">
```

I use jQuery to rewrite the rowkey value to match `.each()` row created.

The end result in the ajax post is a new ajax request for each row. The ajax post looks like this

```
rowkey: 0
application[rows][0][elements][html]: Some HTML here
```

Another ajax request for a new row

```
rowkey: 1
application[rows][1][elements][html]: Some More HTML here
```

Then another if another row is created

```
rowkey: 2
application[rows][2][elements][html]: Some More More HTML here
```

I have used this method before, but now working in wordpress using `update_post_meta` it updates the `wp_postmeta` table with only the last ajax request which in this case is `rowkey: 2` stated above. usually I can get this into an array.

Here is the `update_post_meta`

```
$application['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']] = $_POST['application']['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']];

$application = esc_sql(json_encode($application));

    // Update the post's meta field
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'MY_DATABASE', $application);
```

**NOTE:** This is inside a function and `$post_id` is used as an argument no issues there, just getting all the ajax post values into the database, not the last. Just throwing this out there I remember using `ARRAY_A` not sure if thats relevant here.

The `meta_value` database table looks something like this

```
"rows":{"1":{"elements":{"html":"2"}}}
```

When it should be like this: *Not so sure if this is 100% accurate but it should look similar*

```
"rows":{"1":{"elements":{"html":"1"}}, {"2":{"elements":{"html":"2"}}, {"3":{"elements":{"html":"3"}} }
```

**Final Word:** I hope this was clear enough, and not too long. I really could use help here. I would be more than happy to provide more info, I really want to figure this out. Any information you need just ask.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, i think `$application['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']] = $_POST['application']['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']];` is wrong.

When `$_POST['rowkey']` is a number `$application['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']]` will set to the value of one row in stead of an array of rows.

Example:

```
<?php
$application = array();
$application['rows']=array();
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $application['rows'][$i]=(object)array('elements',(object)array('html'=>($i+1)));
}   

//var_dump($application);
var_dump(json_encode($application['rows'][3])); // your result
var_dump(json_encode((object)$application['rows'])); //expected result
```

So in your code `$application['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']] = $_POST['application']['rows'][$_POST['rowkey']];` to something like `$application['rows'] = $_POST['application']['rows'];`

**NOTE** when `meta_value` expects a json object which exclusive contains objects and not accepts arrays, you will have to cast every array from $_POST to an object. You could use the option JSON_FORCE_OBJECT also (for php>=5.3.0). Objects are surround by {} while array are surround with [].

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling it was this, I got this technique from another application, and used it in the past with no problem. Thanks for the answer let me implement this I know this is definitely on the right track.. Ill post back soon :)